List view button on 'Products' (aka OLIs) related list in opportunity
I have an ask to add a button on the opportunitylineItem related list of the opportunity where that button will download all olis into a csv.
I have hit 2 issues that i'll describe:
I simply haven't managed to add a button to that related list that would simply show the list on the olis in a custom VF.
instead i have managed to add a button on the Opportunity page and when i click i create a csv with the much needed data . though comes issue 2.
I create that csv using contentType="text/csv#filename.csv" in a VF page.
when i click that button on opportunity , a blank VF page appears and the csv gets dowloaded.
So i have 2 questions :

How can i autoclose that blank VF page  ( i have tried so many things like a script in the page window.close() but this doesn't close the window and adds the script code to my csv, I have tried PageReference('javascript:window.close()') in my controller but still the window remains open ...
Is it not possible to add a button on the product related list to export the olis?
Maybe i have looked at it the wrong way but anything i have tried from OpportunityLineItem failed

Here is the code from opportunity
Page :
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="cl_Export2xl"  cache="true" contentType="text/csv#filename.csv" > 
"Col A","Col B",
<apex:repeat value="{!oliList}" var="oli">
{!oli.name},{!oli.id},
</apex:repeat>

</apex:page>

Controller
    public List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList{get;set;}
    public cl_Export2xl(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        oliList = [select id,name, TotalPrice from OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId=:controller.getId()];

    }
public PageReference method(){

return new PageReference('javascript:window.close()');
}

    
}


I changed my thinking and used a LWC for this and added the html button on the opportunity page record , above the OLI related list. Perfect.
